# Need to know all the content fragment applied on a AEM page using API

Tags: java, content-management-system, aem, aem-6

I have the page path (or page object) in my servlet , now i need to find all the content fragment applied on this page.

Like using ExperienceFragmentsService i can get all the "Experience fragment" applied on the page. In the same way how can i get all the "Content Fragment" applied on the page? Is there any API available for this?

Answer (score 0):

ContentFragmentManager might help. [Here](https://aemdeveloper.wordpress.com/2017/08/22/create-access-the-content-fragment-programmatically/) is a blog that helped me to create content fragments programatically.
Or you can try querybuilder api.